# Compile xaml using Roslyn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, msbuild, roslyn

Is there a way to use Roslyn compiler to compile a WPF UserControl?

- Let's say you'd want to compile an assembly containing standard C# code and WPF controls (XAML and xaml.cs files) without any csproj of course.
- I've found a lot on the web on how to compile a DLL using Roslyn, nothing on how to handle XAML files?
- I know that Visual Studio (or MSBuild) creates a temporary generated file and embed a BAML file in the resulting assembly. So maybe if I could find a way to generate this intermediate file I could use it, but all I have found is PresentationBuildTasks.MarkupCompilePass that needs in the end a csproj (ok, I may generate a project on the fly, but I hope to find something simpler).

Comment: Roslyn is just C# (and VB) compiler, it doesn't know anything about XAML. But you should be able to use the Roslyn compiler in combination with XAML tools just like the old C# compiler.

Comment: Xaml tools? Do you mean use MsBuild to generate baml?

Comment: Yeah, or whatever msbuild actually uses to generate the BAML and the partial class.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationBuildTasks/src/BuildTasks/Microsoft/Build/Tasks/Windows/MarkupCompilePass1.cs does not seem to need a csproj.

Comment: @SLaks The link was recently updated: [MarkupCompilePass1.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationBuildTasks/BuildTasks/Microsoft/Build/Tasks/Windows/MarkupCompilePass1.cs).

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to compile XAML to C#, check out the XAML Code Behind Generator, see http://xamlgenerator.codeplex.com/.

Its a plugin for Visual Studio 2010 that allows you to compile XAML into the equivalent C#.